# Diophantine equation $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have a pretty difficult math question that I have no idea even how to begin. Here it goes:

> Find the nonzero integers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 2$?

I would assume that at least one of the integers would be negative. Also, I got as far as $(a+b+c)^3 = 2^3$ but I'm not sure what good this will do.

(So, not to cower in shame I made a mistake above seeing as how  $(a+b+c)^3 \ne 2^3$. I admit I failed there. But how to work this equation?)

Comment: How did you get to $(a+b+c)^3$?!

Comment: Daw man, you're right. Sleep deprivation is causing my basic algebra skills to lack! Now, I'm even further behind that I 'believed' I was...

Comment: How did you get $(a+b+c)^3=8$?

Comment: There are infinitely many non-zero solutions. 
$$(1+6x^3)^3 + (1-6x^3)^3 + (-6x^2)^3 = 2$$ The key is start from a known solution $(a,b,c) = (1,1,0)$ of the equation and play with it.

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

In $1908$, A.S. Werebrusov found the following parametrization of $x$, $y$, and $z$ for the sum of three cubes $x^3+y^3+z^3$ equal to $2$:
$$
(1 + 6t^3)^3 + (1 − 6t^3)^3 + (−6t^2)^3 = 2.
$$
A further references here is L.J. Mordell, On Sums of Three Cubes, Journal of the London Mathematical Society $17$ (1942), 139–144. There are several discussions about the sum of three integer cubes, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-three-cubes-in-infinitely-many-ways) and the references given therein.