# Parametric solutions to $x^3+y^3+z^3 = N$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

With the recent discovery by S. Huisman (actually in 2016) of
$$−284650292555885^3+ 66229832190556^3 + 283450105697727^3 = 74$$

and discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1565427/4781), I decided to revisit this topic. We have an infinite family of parameterizations for $N=1$,

---

$$(1 - 9n^3)^3 + (9n^4)^3 + (3n - 9n^4)^3 = 1$$

---

$$(1 + 9n^3 + 648n^6 - 3888n^9)^3 +\\ (-135n^4 + 3888n^{10})^3 + (-3n - 81n^4 + 
        1296n^7 - 3888n^{10})^3 = 1$$

---

and so on for ***all*** degrees $k=4,10,16,\dots =6m+4.$ [Only one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346332/sum-of-three-cubes-x3y3z3-2-and-parametric-solutions) (so far) for $N=2$,

$$(-6n^2)^3 + (1 + 6n^3)^3 + (1 - 6n^3)^3 = 2$$

I went over [Huisman's $15254$ solutions](https://arxiv.org/src/1604.07746v1/anc/sumofthreecubes_20160426.txt). The $N$ with the most number $\text{#}$ of solutions are,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
N&\text{#}\\
\hline
792&96\\ 
720&89\\
755&83\\ 
918&80\\
638&80\\ 
883&79\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

So in the "small" finite range ($10^{15}$) that Huisman searched, then
$$x^3+y^3+z^3 = 792$$ 
already has $96$ solutions. *If the range is infinite, does it (and others) in fact have infinitely many solutions like $N=1$?*

**P.S.** Using Huisman's database, I found,

$$(-2n - 3 n^4)^3 + (1 + 3 n^3 + 3 n^6)^3 + (-3 n^3 - 3 n^6)^3 = n^3 + 1$$

Of course, if we let $n\to-n$, this solves $N=n^3-1$ as well.

> **Q:** Any other parametric solution to $x^3+y^3+z^3 = N$ where $N$ is ***simple*** in form like $N=1,\,2,\,n^3\pm1$ and is not a cube?

Comment: I tried looking at $N = n^3\pm c$ for other integer $c$, but it was hard to find a pattern.

Comment: I think your question belongs to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/) community, according to the fact that such field is not well explored yet and, perhaps your question is still an open problem.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an infinite number of parametrizations for some fixed $N$?

Comment: Or, at least, more than one?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen: That is a very important question for this topic. It is known only for $N=1$. But other $N$ have many, like $N=720$ has 89 solutions, and is just begging to be parameterized, if indeed possible.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I did not think much about those parametrizations questions, although I am partially aware that we lack a general enough theory of parametrizations of at least simple enough Diophantine equations. These special cases are probably just glimpses of far more general theory.

Comment: I doubt that there can be an infinite number of different parametrizations for fixed $N$ because then $$\dfrac {1}{x^3+y^3+z^3}$$ would be too dense near zero.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen: Actually, there is for $N=1$. I've added the next smallest in the post.

Comment: To the moderator: Thanks. :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Do you want to chat about all of this, to teach me what you know?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen: I normally don't do chat. My apologies.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Me neither. Ok if that is your decision.

Answer (score 2):

Seiji Tomita has written an article in which he has given multiple parametrization for which the sums of three cubes is $N=(square)$ 
The link is given below.

```
     http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph87e.html
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not a answer.